# Java file locking

Tags: java, file-io, locking

I've written the following helper class that should allow me to get an exclusive lock on a file, then do something with it.

```
public abstract class LockedFileOperation {

    public void execute(File file) throws IOException {

        if (!file.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();
        // Get an exclusive lock on the whole file
        FileLock lock = channel.lock();
        try {
            lock = channel.lock();
            doWithLockedFile(file);
        } finally {
            lock.release();
        }
    }

    public abstract void doWithLockedFile(File file) throws IOException;
}
```

Here's a unit test I wrote, which creates a subclass of `LockedFileOperation` that attempts to rename the locked file

```
public void testFileLocking() throws Exception {

    File file = new File("C:/Temp/foo/bar.txt");
    final File newFile = new File("C:/Temp/foo/bar2.txt");

    new LockedFileOperation() {

        @Override
        public void doWithLockedFile(File file) throws IOException {
            if (!file.renameTo(newFile)) {
                throw new IOException("Failed to rename " + file + " to " + newFile);
            }
        }
    }.execute(file);
}
```

When I run this test, an `OverlappingFileLockException` is thrown when `channel.lock()` is called. It's unclear to me why this is happening, because I only ever try to lock this file once.

In any event, the JavaDocs for the `lock()` method say that:

> An invocation of this method will
>   block until the region can be locked,
>   this channel is closed, or the
>   invoking thread is interrupted,
>   whichever comes first.

So even if the file was already locked it seems that the `lock()` method should block, rather than throwing an `OverlappingFileLockException`.

I guess there's something fundamental about `FileLock` that I'm misunderstanding. I'm running on Windows XP (in case that's relevant).

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are locking twice the file and never release the first lock:

```
    // Get an exclusive lock on the whole file
    FileLock lock = channel.lock();
    try {
        lock = channel.lock();
        doWithLockedFile(file);
    } finally {
        lock.release();
    }
```

As you reuse the var lock, where do you release the first?

You code should be:

```
    // Get an exclusive lock on the whole file
    FileLock lock = null;
    try {
        lock = channel.lock();
        doWithLockedFile(file);
    } finally {
        if(lock!=null) {
           lock.release();
         }
    }
```